# Using axios with TS, and property doesn't exist

Tags: typescript, express, axios

I am trying to type axios response. This is how the type of the response looks like:

```js
export interface GetBreedsResponse {
  data: {
    message: Breed[]
  }
}
```

In my router file I am doing this:

```
router.get("/breeds", async (_req: Request, res: Response) => {
  try {
    const apiResponse = await axios.get<GetBreedsResponse>("https://url");
    let breeds : Breed  = await apiResponse.data.message;
    // some code
  }catch (err: unknown) {
    // some code
  }
});
```

I am getting an error that property `message` doesn't exist on `GetBreedsResponse`. I assume it has something to do that `message` is nested inside of `data` property but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: axios already sets the property `data`. You need to access `message` via `apiResponse.data.data.message`, if your api also returns a `data` property

Answer (score 1):

`GetBreedsResponse` is supposed to describe the shape of the body of the HTTP response.

The `data` property is not part of that response body, it is where axios puts the response body.

```js
export interface GetBreedsResponse {
    message: Breed[]
  }
}
```

As TJ points out, you are also trying to assign `message` (`Breed[]` - an array) to `breeds` (`Breed` - not an array) so your types don't match.

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues:

1. You're using `breeds: Breed`, but `message`'s type is `Breed[]` (an array). From the plural `breeds`, I suspect you probably wanted `Breed[]`.
2. The type you give as a type argument to `axios.get` (and others) is the type for the `data` property of the `AxiosResponse` you get, so you don't include the `data` member in your type. Just:

```typescript
export interface GetBreedsResponse {
    message: Breed[];
}
```

...and then there's no need to put an explicit type annotation on `breeds` at all (it'll be `Breed[]`):

```typescript
export interface GetBreedsResponse {
    message: Breed[];
}

router.get("/breeds", async (_req: Request, res: Response) => {
    try {
        const apiResponse = await axios.get<GetBreedsResponse>("https://url");
        let breeds = await apiResponse.data.message;
        // some code
    } catch (err: unknown) {
        // some code
    }
});
```

Comment: The `Breed` part was a typo. Thank you for clarifying that I am typing the data part.